# SQL Server 2005: Integration Services Stored Packages is empty. Why?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am trying to import, export SSIS packages. I know they are there. When I query msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90 I get 22 packages. But when I connect to Integration Services on the server, the stored packages folder is empty. What is going on?

And I have already checked MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml. It is set up with the standard, default settings.

Answer (score 5):

The packages themselves are stored in the msdb sysdtspackaes90 table.

> It’s important to note that the SSIS
>   server isn’t aware of packages stored
>   in the File System until those
>   packages have been imported to the
>   File System folder in the SSIS
>   service.

...

> While the SQL Server Management Studio
>   is shipped using the default folder
>   locations of MSDB and File System, you
>   can freely add new folders to this
>   structure using the Create New Folder
>   option. When you create a new folder
>   beneath the File System system folder,
>   a new directory will be created in the
>   file system. By default, these
>   directories are located in the
>   c:\Program Files\SQL
>   Server\90\Packages directory.
>   Importing packages to a File System
>   folder will result in the package
>   being copied to the like named
>   directory in the file system. For
>   folders that are created under the
>   MSDB folder, a new entry is added to
>   the sysdtspackackefolder90 table that
>   tracks the folder structure. However,
>   it’s important to realize that the
>   packages themselves are still stored
>   in the msdb sysdtspackaes90 table. The
>   Folders option in the SQL Server
>   Management Studio essentially gives
>   you a way to apply and organization
>   structure to your packages, enabling
>   you to group like packages together.

[Managing and Deploying SQL Server Integration Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966389.aspx)

Anyway, I recommend to install all SPs.

Comment: my friend, what you say is that he can change the folders of existing packages (which you are right), but what he says is that he can't find them physically - although he sees them in the MSDB table, he can't see them while browsing the packages folder in the Integration Service. I believe that he wants a way to recover the packages from that MSDB table to a folder in IS .. :-)

Comment: @Marian you guess, I guess

Comment: @Marian: yes that's correct. Why are they not showing up in the folder in IS? @Igor: that was very helpful, and I really appreciate the information. But Marian is right, I can see them in the table, but they are not there when I browse to them. . .  Any ideas?